# Read replicas are created in wrong AZ when adding new shards through Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elasticache

I'm facing an odd error when updating my Elasticache Cloudformation Stack, at the moment it has 2 shards and every shard has a replica node, I define the AZ I want them to belong to, like this:

```
    "MyRedisCluster": {
            "Properties": {
                "Engine": "redis",
                "MultiAZEnabled": "true",
                "NodeGroupConfiguration": [
                    {
                        "NodeGroupId": "0001",
                        "PrimaryAvailabilityZone": "eu-west-1b",
                        "ReplicaAvailabilityZones": [
                            "eu-west-1a"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "NodeGroupId": "0002",
                        "PrimaryAvailabilityZone": "eu-west-1c",
                        "ReplicaAvailabilityZones": [
                            "eu-west-1b"
                        ]
                    },
                ],
                
                "NumNodeGroups": 2,
                "ReplicasPerNodeGroup": 1,
            },
            "Type": "AWS::ElastiCache::ReplicationGroup",
            "UpdatePolicy": {
                "UseOnlineResharding": "true"
            }
        }
```

When I create my stack everything works correctly, my primary and replica nodes are created correctly in their appropriate AZ.

Now I want to add a new shard, so I added a new `NodeGroupConfiguration` object and set `NumNodeGroups` to 3. The update process works fine, my third shard is created, but the thing is that the primary and replica nodes are created in the wrong AZ, as you can see my third shard should have its primary node in `eu-west-1a` and its replica node in `eu-west-1c`, but they are created the other way around, primary node in `eu-west-1c` and replica in `eu-west-1a`.

```
{
    "NodeGroupId": "0003",
    "PrimaryAvailabilityZone": "eu-west-1a",
    "ReplicaAvailabilityZones": [
        "eu-west-1c"
    ]
}
```

This is soo weird, I tried to use AWS CLI to add it [modify-replication-group-shard-configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticache/modify-replication-group-shard-configuration.html) and it works just fine. Can we say this is a Cloudformation bug?

Comment: If you have access to AWS support, I'd ask them to clarify. If this is indeed a bug, they'll also be able to pass it along to the responsible development team.

Comment: If you _don't_ have access to AWS developer support, I recommend you consider getting it for this purpose.  (In my limited experience) they've been quite helpful.  It's only $29 a month (US at least...)

Comment: Yeah, I created a new issue here: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/899 but I should ask AWS support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS has confirmed this is an error from their side. I created a AWS support case and also added a new issue in their cloudformation repo.

https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/899